# redis snapshot location not as specified in config

Tags: redis

After running fine for a while, I am getting write error on my redis instance:

```
(error) MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.
```

In the log I see:

```
 9948:C 22 Mar 20:49:32.241 # Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /var/spool/cron) for saving: Read-only file system
```

However, my redis config file is /etc/redis/redis.conf as confirmed by:

```
 redis-cli -p 6379 info | grep 'config_file'
 config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

And there I have:

```
 dir /mnt/data/redis
```

And indeed, there is a snapshot there.

But despite the above, redis now thinks my data directory is

```
 redis-cli -p 6379 CONFIG GET dir
 1) "dir"
 2) "/var/spool/cron"
```

Corresponding to the error I was getting as quoted above.

Can anyone tell me why/how my data directory is changing after redis starts, such that it is no longer what is specified in the config file?

Comment: Someone might have modified your `dir` config with `CONFIG SET dir /var/spool/cron` command.

Comment: @for_stack no one else has access to that machine--at least no one is upposed to.  Although I did start noticing this once I opened the port to the world to be able to access it from other servers. Is this a common attack?  Perhaps I need to add some middleware to prevent evilness.

Comment: Looks like opening redis to the universe is just a terrible idea.  I will restrict to my security group and/or implement a middleware.  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/75-of-public-facing-redis-servers-are-infected-with-malware-heres-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: Yes, it's always a bad idea to open Redis to the public. Also check [this](http://antirez.com/news/96). It seems someone tried to hack you server.

Comment: @for_stack and succeeded.  At least so far as changing config and erase data.  Although the attempt to write to /var/spool/cron failed as that is read only from the point of view of redis.  Security By Obscurity for the Fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is that the redis server was hacked and the configuration changed, which is very easy to do as it turns out. (I should point out that I had no reason to think it wasn't easy to do.  I just assumed security by obscurity was sufficient in this case--wrong.  No matter, this was just a playground not any sort of production server).

So don't open your redis port to the world.  Use security groups if on AWS to limit access to machines that need it, or use `AUTH` (which is still not awesome because then all clients need to know the single password which also apparently gets sent in the clear), or have some middleware controlling access.

Hacking redis is easy to do, can compromise your data, and even enable unauthorized SSH access to your server.  And that's why you shouldn't highline.